# Replicate a row based on a conditional

Tags: python, pandas

I've read through at least 10 answers to very similar questions but none of them work and/or are quite what I need. I have a large-ish dataframe where I need it to find a particular row and create a copy of the entire row. So for example:

Before:

```
index    price   quantity    flavor    
0        1.45    6           vanilla   
1        1.85    3           berry   
2        2.25    2           double chocolate
```

After:

```
index    price   quantity    flavor    
0        1.45    6           vanilla   
1        1.85    3           berry   
2        2.25    2           double chocolate
3        1.85    3           berry
```

What would seem to work based on my knowledge of pandas and python is this:

```
df.loc[df.index.max() + 1,:] = df.loc[df['flavor'] == 'berry'].values
```

However I get this error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Bear in mind that I have no idea where in the database "berry" might be (other than it will be in the "flavor" column). (edit to add) Also there may be more than one "berry" so it would need to find them all.

Thoughts?

Comment: do you think, there could be multiple `berry` say all of them you want to add in the last rows?

Comment: Yes I realized that was part of the problem after posting. See edit.

Comment: My answer already tackles that, append does supports the multiple rows at a time.

Answer (score 3):

So, this is probably what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"quantity":[6, 3, 2], "flavor":["vanilla", "berry", "double chocolate"], "price":[1.45, 1.85, 2.25]})
df = df.append(df.loc[df['flavor'] == 'berry']).reset_index()
df
#output
    flavor  price   quantity
0   vanilla 1.45    6
1   berry   1.85    3
2   double chocolate    2.25    2
3   berry   1.85    3
```

Just using `append` and resetting index should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a slightly different answer than what @user2906838 suggested. Because it is possible that there is more than one 'berry' in the dataframe, I created a new dataframe and then concatenated them:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'quantity':[6, 3, 2], 'flavor':['vanilla', 'berry', 'double chocolate'], 'price':[1.45, 1.85, 2.25]})
df_flavor = pd.DataFrame
df_flavor.append(df.loc[df['flavor'] == 'berry'], sort = False)
df = pd.concat([df, df_flavor], sort = False, ignore_index = True)
```

This worked fine, but would love to hear if there are other solutions!